# using reflection to assign a float

Tags: java, reflection, floating-point

```
} else if (fieldType.equals(Float.TYPE)) {
  return random.nextFloat(); //catches primitive
} else if (fieldType.equals(Boolean.TYPE)) {
  return random.nextBoolean();
} else if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)) {
  return random.nextInt(Byte.MAX_VALUE) + 1; //catches Float
```

How can I catch the primitive and Object in same place ?

( Where `Class<?> fieldType` )

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear, but I've had years of experience deciphering questions on the Sun/Oracle forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare with `Float.TYPE` and `Float.class`.

First is the primitive, latter is the wrapper.

I.e. `if(fieldType.equals(Float.class) || fieldType.equals(Float.TYPE))`

Comment: Also, `float.class` is equivalent to `Float.TYPE`, if you find it more consistent.